# Comparison of $ ( 1^a + 2^a+ ... n^a)^n$ and $n^n(n!)^a $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, inequality, contest-math

For a given real number $a>0$ , define $ d_n =( 1^a + 2^a+ ... n^a)^n $ and 
$ b_n = n^n(n!)^a $ for $ n = 1,2,\ldots$

Then

a) $ d_n< b_n $ for $ n> 1$,

b) There exists an integer $n>1$ such that $ d_n<b_n $,

c) $d_n > b_n $,

d) There exist integers $n$ and $m$ both larger than one such that $d_n > b_n$ and $d_m<d_m$.

My attempt: Uphill now , for the lack of a better method that I could figure out , I tried solving this for $a = 1$. In this way I could utilise the formulae for summation of natural numbers and proceed forward. However even there I couldn't get a perfect answer.

Should I try induction? (I really don't think that induction is the only method to solve the problem)

I am looking for a more general approach to solve the problem, other than induction

Comment: Added them in the new edit .

Comment: The only question that would take some work is to decide whether either (a) or (d) is correct for some value of $a$.  But this might mean that neither is correct for all $a$, and therefore we are left with...

Comment: @ abiessu The correct answer as mentioned in the question bank is c)

Comment: Then I'm missing something...  The way it is written, $a_n$ is never greater than $b_n$ for $n\gt 1$...

Comment: My fault check the updated question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM/GM applied to $1^a,2^a,\dots,n^a$, we have $d_n>b_n$. The inequality is strict because the terms are obviously unequal.

[AM/GM = Arithmetic Mean/Geometric Mean inequality]

Comment: @abiessu So in that case the claim is that $(1+2^a)^2>4\cdot2^a$. That looks true to me, even for small positive $a$. If $a=0$ (disallowed in the question) then the inequality would not be strict, both sides would be 4.

Comment: Correct, I had made an error in my initial calculations.